# Codeigniter - a dynamic sidebar

Tags: codeigniter, sidebar

I only started with this a couple of days ago, so this may be a silly question...

I have an admin area with its own directory "admin" within the controller folder. So if the user is in the admin area, I want a sidebar to show. But obviously there will be a fair few "pages" (controllers) within the admin area. I have Clients, Services and Dashboard.

In the sidebar (on all pages) I want a list of clients and services so when clicked, it goes to a page and display info for that client/service.

I sort of have it working with add_service(), edit_service(), view_services() etc... but in each of these methods, it seems like I need to load services AND clients models, and pass the data back to each view... in all methods? So if I want to add a service, I click "add service" and it takes me to the add_service(). Do I need the below 4 lines in each method?

```
$this->load->model('client_model');
$this->load->model('services_model');
$data['clients'] = $this->client_model->get_clients();
$data['services'] = $this->services_model->get_services();
```

I have read about widgets, but not sure if that's what I need exactly.

Thanks

Comment: you can do with libraries. Hope you have sidebar in  template. If so, you can load your template from library. So you can write this code in library

Answer (score 0):

As you read, all you need is HMVC. This will create a "widget" with your controller, model and views, and you'll be able of calling "a whole": A part of the website wich manage its own part.

One solution is implement https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc into your code, you create a module called "client", and in your "admin" controller you call it. You'll get your client table there, and in your controller "client" you'll be able of call it too, and you'll have exactly the same behaviour. I've implemented wiredesignz HMVC quite times and I think is the solution for your trouble. Anyway, you could also check https://github.com/Bigwebmaster/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc, which is a fork with improvements into the code.

About your sidebar, you'll have to call the widget you'll create with your clients, and you'll have it quickly with only one call, because the module will manage all the behaviour